# apache server in ubuntu 16.04 is not responding to port-forwarding in router

Tags: apache-2.2, router, port-forwarding, ubuntu-16.04

apache server in ubuntu 16.04 is not responding to port-forwarding in router i tried a lot to make apache server to make it repond to port-forwarding like changing the settings of ufw and apache sever its not working with public ip address from outside network or internet it is working inside the home network

> Blockquote

Comment: Is the 'listen' address the same as the IP Address you are port forwarding to? Is apache actually running? The service is often called httpd. What do the error logs say? Logs are usually /var/log/httpd/ where there will be both error & access logs.

Comment: it is not working with public address @AdmiralNoisyBottom

Comment: Ok, so it works on the ip address used by your server. If the port forwarding is directed at the correct IP and port then something on your server is blocking it. Does it work from another pc on the same network? Does the access or error log mention anything?

Comment: yes its working in same network what to do@AdmiralNoisyBottom

Comment: It's hard to say what might be going on. I don't know if you are self hosted or not but port 80 might be closed by your ISP. Perhaps an online port scan for open ports might give more information. Or temporarily put apache on another port, like 20000 (high) add another port forward and try urp http://yoursite.com:20000.